Add or Edit https binding?
I have an IIS 10 running several web applications under "Default Web Site".
I want to enable SSL binding for one of the web applications under "Default Web Site", say "dev-org-iis.domain.com/MyWebApp/Home.aspx"
I have a Org/Domain certificate installed in the server.
There already is an entry for https under Bindings for the "Default Web Site". And the bindings look like the screenshot

Screenshot
Should I "Edit" the https entry and choose the ssl certificate that i have created from the domain/organization
Or should i add another http binding using the "Add" button and choose my certificate in order to apply ssl for the specific web application?


Not related to programming but server administration. 2) Not using the right terms if you check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis. In short, if you enable HTTPS on an IIS site, all its applications/virtual directories are affected (and that's desired).


No, when you use https in Site Bindings, you can choose different certificates, so one certificate will not apply to all web applications running under the Default Website.
